# How to make all the commands which come with git available globally from the windows command line?

Tags: windows, git

Not long ago I found out a precious thing which comes with the git install:

http://git-scm.com/download/win

From git's bin folder on the command line you have almost a linux console available. Commands like curl, touch, kill, ssh, grep and lots of others. The problem is that when you move out of the bin folder, of course they become unavailable. Is it possible somehow to make these commands available globally from the windows command line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply add the full path to you "bin" folder (e.g. `c:\git\bin\`) into Windows "PATH" environmental variable.

As opposed to repeating how to do that here, plenty of help on the web.

http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm

Note: you may need to close and re-open the command window you are in if you add through the control panel.

Answer (score 1):

Use this one [**Git Shell**](https://windows.github.com/) from Github

Has some cool git features in it, much better than default windows command prompt.
Few good points are:

- Tab completion
- Prompt for current branch
- Colors highlighting